# Find the ratio of the lengths of chord AB to arc AB

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, ratio

The chord AB of a circle subtends an angle of 60 degrees at the centre.
Find the ratio of the lengths of chord AB to arc AB.

I tried $sin60 = AB/r = √3/2$

Therefore $r = 2$ and $chordAB = √3$

Therefore $arcAB = rθ = 2 * 60 = 180$

and so the ratio is $√3/180$

This just doesn't seem right and is definitely not the right answer. Any hints? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's $$\frac{R}{\frac{2\pi R}{6}}=\frac{3}{\pi}.$$

Comment: ah yes, I understand now that the arcAB is simply a 6th of 2. Could you explain how you know the length of the chord is R?

Comment: @Jay M Because it's a side-lengths of the equilateral triangle.

Comment: right of course.. because the angle was 60degrees. I definitely have some gaps in my geometry knowledge to fill! Thank you

Comment: You are welcome!